# Python: How to add hooks for controlling (stop/start/pause/resume) an endless loop from a second program?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside2

I have code that starts a while loop and runs until I hard kill it with Control-C. I'd like to make this a bit nicer by adding some way to communicate with the code to make it stop a bit more gracefully. Eventually, I'd like to control this from a PyQt application with a start/stop button and a pause/resume button. How would I add some hooks into the code to allow for this sort of control?

The current code looks like this:

```
def handle_notifications(dao_notifications):

    # fetch notifications
    while True:

        try:
            # store received notifications into the database
            for notification in next(notifications_generator):
                dao_notifications.insert(notification)

        except StopIteration:
            continue


def notifications_generator():

    # create a socket to listen for notification events
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sockt:

        # bind the listener port of the local host to the socket instance
        sockt.bind((_LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS, _LISTENER_PORT))

        # start the socket listening
        sockt.listen()

        # continually receive notifications and yield
        while True:

            # accept a communication connection on the socket
            connection, connection_address = sockt.accept()
            with connection:

                # receive bytes of data from the socket, decode as Unicode string
                xml = connection.recv(20480).decode("utf-8")

                # only try to yield values if we've actually received data
                if len(xml) > 0:

                    # parse the XML into a dictionary
                    notifications_soap = xmltodict.parse(xml)

                    # yield the notification messages as an iterable
                    notifications = \
                        notifications_soap["SOAP-ENV:Envelope"]["SOAP-ENV:Body"]["wsnt:Notify"]["wsnt:NotificationMessage"]
                    yield notifications
```

Perhaps this is a use case for signal handling? For example, I can write a handler for SIGINT to pause/suspend the execution (keep sleeping until another signal to resume arrives) and one for SIGTERM to gracefully clean up before exit, then the PyQt application will issue the appropriate signals to control execution. Is there a good/simple example of this?

Comment: Put it all in a separate thread and communicate with the gui using qt-signals (as opposed to the python signals module). There are dozens of examples showing how to do that on SO and elsewhere.

Comment: I've not come across any useful examples after what seems like an extensive search (using searches such as "python pyside2 qt signals process control suspend" etc.). Maybe my Google-Fu is weak -- can anyone provide a link to just one of the dozens of examples that I've failed to find?

Comment: For me, simply searching for "pyqt thread" on either SO or google brings up all the examples.

Comment: I've not found one yet that shows how to send a signal from a Qt GUI application written in Python to a separate, non-Qt aware Python application. BTW I've managed to accomplish this by having my Python/Qt (pyside2) GUI application communicate with the Python application it should control via messages across sockets. Maybe this is as good as I can expect without both sides having Qt signaling built in (since the application to be controlled isn't using Qt and hence can't handle Qt signals)? Or can I include pyside2 in the second application in order to make it capable of handling signals?

Comment: The body of your question doesn't really make it clear that there **must** be two separate processes. But if that is the case, any kind of [IPC mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication#Approaches) will do, and the particular gui toolkit used by the controlling application is mostly irrelevant. However, it isn't clear that two processes are really required. Why can't you just import the other code and run it in a separate thread?